# How to chain multiple DbSet.Include() in a loop?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

How to include in loop?
I want to specify related objects to include in query.

I have next function

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Include(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> result = null;

        //two includes are ok:
        //IQueryable<TEntity> result2 = null;
        //if (includes.Count() > 1)
        //{
            //result2 = dbset.Include(includes[0]).Include(includes[1]);
        //}

        //include in loop is not ok:
        foreach (var exp in includes)
        {
            result = dbset.Include(exp);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If I uncomment commented code that result2 will be ok. But result is not ok.

Strange is that if I debug loop step by step, in every iteration checking result then result is ok. But if I am not checking result step by step that include work just for last expresion.

Do you have any idea why this is not working and how to fix?

---

Edit:
this is fix:

```
    result = dbset;
    foreach (var exp in includes)
    {
        result = result.Include(exp);
    }
```

Comment: In every turn of your foreach the variable `result` gets a new value with the current include.

Comment: What it is doing when you say "not ok". Is it showing last result, as you are overiding previous here in the statement result = dbset.Include(exp); you need to something result.Concat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you keep overriding the value of `result` with the result of a single `Include()` call on the `dbSet`.

You need to *concatenate* those calls as follows:

```
foreach (var exp in includes)
{
    result = result.Include(exp);
}
```

Comment: O god, I am going to kill myself.